# Visual C++ to Visual Studio 2019 - A Dependent DLL was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, migration

I'm in the process of migrating some legacy MFC applications that were, and are still supported by Visual Studio 2008.

The automated migration that's packaged in with Visual Studio 2019 allows the program and supporting libraries to successfully build; however, at execution this error appeared:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because MSCVR90D.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

After further research, this appears to be a Visual Studio debug DLL. After finding the DLL and dropping it into my debug folder, I receive a brand new error:

```
Debug Error!

R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library without using a manifest.
```

I've followed the various StackOverflow and MSDN troubleshooting steps that touch on this issue, mostly changing settings within the Linker and Manifest settings, but to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas? Be it with resolving the DLL issue, or the manifest issue that follows its explicit inclusion in the project.

Comment: Can't you statically link to the runtime library instead?

Comment: Could you expand on that? I have never had to statically link a runtime library in Visual Studio.

Comment: The option will be in the project settings dialog.

Comment: I think you need to figure out what part of your code still is using  the old runtime. Maybe you are using some external library that was built with the old compiler.

Comment: That is the answer I really didn't want to hear!

Comment: There are few things more fun than arsing around with project settings.

Comment: On "Maybe you are using some external library that was built with the old compiler", the debug output will tell you which libraries are being loaded and when, so you might be able to cover this one off fairly quickly.

Comment: When starting back at square one, the `dependent dll was not found` error, is there a way to pinpoint what code is requiring that dll?

Comment: Good "Dependency viewer in C++". Download it. And away you go!

Comment: This thing: https://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: There is a replacement for that that fixes a few problems here: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: The `*D` suffix is definitely suspect, unless it's a debug build. Also, check the Visual Studio output. It will list DLL paths as the program is loaded. Likely, it will show the DLL that loads `MSCVR90D.dll` right before `MSCVR90D.dll` itself

Comment: This is a Debug build, but the error persists even in a Release build, same DLL, sans the D.

Comment: The last DLL that is loaded before the threads exit is `uxtheme.dll` any ideas with that one?

Comment: @satazero I suggest you could try to set Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd): Select the `Configuration Properties` > `C/C++` > `Code Generation `property page, and modify the `Runtime Library` property.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Following your suggestion, I set the `Runtime Library` to `(/MTd)` which gave me the error: `Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds`, following THAT error I switched it to `(/MD)` which brought me right back to where I started!